# Zurb Stack for email is failing at inlining process

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, html-email

I seem to be running into a problem with the Zurb Stack while developing an HTML with Foundation for Emails (v2). The "watch" gulp process works fine, but when I perform the "build" process, it crashed on the inlining process. If I remove this from the gulp series, the build process is fine..but I get no inlining of the code.

When the error happens, I first see what appears to be table-ized and inline-styled code. Then I get the following error:

```
Details:
    fileName: /home/dave/email-projects/onboarding1/dist/index.html
    domainEmitter: [object Object]
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: false
[11:53:28] 'build' errored after 2.15 s
[11:53:28] 'default' errored after 2.15 s
Error: foundation-emails-template@1.0.0 build: `gulp --production`
Exit status 1
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/dave/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.2/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:217:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/dave/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.2/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
```

Even with this, I have taken the table-ized HTML, the /dist app.css, and run it though the online inlining tool. Although it does render, it generates layout issues, and the elements that use visibility settings either show both items (small and large) or nothing.

At this point I can't tell if it's the app config or something in the HTML/CSS that it doesn't like. However, I have taken a previous successful project, and it fails the same way.

Environment:

- Ubuntu 15.10
- node.js v.0.10.25
- npm v.3.9.5
- gulp cli v.3.9.1

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. There was a simple typo that the terminal inliner was choking on. The html text output in the terminal was they key. However, you need to set your terminal to "unlimited" scroll-back. It is so long, you will lose this in the terminal history. Once done, re-run your `foundation build` command. You will get the error, but you can scroll up to the start of the error message.

In my case, there was typo with two double quotes in a row. This is a pretty common error that would think the system would fail more elegantly on.

This **ALSO** caused on the online Zurb Inliner tool to simple not work, as in..you click the button and nothing happens..no error, nothing. I forced an error in the Inliner tool to ensure it was working, but still did nothing with my typo in there. Very odd.

In any event, it was a typo, but it generated another problem for me ... that's fr another entry.